# Are marginals of a jointly Gaussian sequence always Gaussian?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, central-limit-theorem

Are marginal distributions of the random variables comprising a jointly gaussian random vector always Gaussian?

This stems from my confusion with the Central Limit Theorem which loosely states that sum of a sufficiently large number of independent random variables tends to be normal under mild constraints irrespective of the distributions of each random variable.

The second statement is that of a Gaussia Random process in time, which states that "for any number n of samples, any sampling times $t_1,t_2\ldots ,t_n$, and any scalar constants $a_1,a_2\ldots a_n$, the linear combination $a_1X(t_1)+a_2X(t_2)+\ldots +a_nX(t_n)$ is a jointly gaussian random variable."

Now, for Jointly gaussian random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$, any linear combination of these random variables is a gaussian random variable. Then, for all but one scalar coefficients $a_i$ set to zero, the resulting random variable would still be a Gaussian and hence, the marginal $X_i$ would be gaussian.

But, CLT states that it could be of any distribution!

I am confused with these two lines of thought. Please remedy my confusion.

Comment: The CLT says *absolutely nothing* about finite linear combinations of random variables.  It asserts a *limiting* distribution *is* Gaussian, not that it "could be any distribution"!  Why don't you [review our posts on the CLT](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=central%20limit%20theorem)?

Comment: It is worth adding that the converse statement need not be true: R.V.s can have marginal Normal distributions but their joint distribution might not Multivariate Normal. A simple example for Bivariate Normal: let $X$ be a standard Normal R.V. and $S$ be a random sign R.V. which is independent of $X$. $S$ takes on values $-1$ or $1$ with equal probabilities of $\frac{1}{2}$. Now define $Y=SX$, which is also Normally distributed (by symmetry of the Normal distribution). Now, $P(X+Y=0)=P(S=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... Since $X+Y$ is a linear combination of two standard Normal R.V.s which is not Normal, $(X,Y)$ is not Bivariate Normal. $\:\:\:$

*This neat example was taken from Blitzstein's Introduction to Probability book*

Comment: @slazien See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81469, and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120861.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assertion "$a_1X(t_1)+a_2X(t_2)+\ldots +a_nX(t_n)$ is a **jointly** gaussian random variable" in your second statement is almost completely correct: $a_1X(t_1)+a_2X(t_2)+\ldots +a_nX(t_n)$ **is** indeed a gaussian random variable but since it is just one variable all by itself, the adjective "jointly" is not needed.

**Definition:** A random process $\{X(t) \colon t \in \mathbb T\}$is called a *Gaussian* random process if all the finite-dimensional distributions
of the process are (multivariate) Gaussian distributions.

A more prolix description is that
each random variable $X(t), t \in \mathbb T$ is a Gaussian random
variable, and for any integer $n \geq 2$ time instants $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n \in \mathbb T$, the
$n$ random variables $X(t_1)$, $X(t_2)$, $\ldots X(t_n)$,
are *jointly* Gaussian random variables.

**Definition:** The random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are said
have a *multivariate* Gaussian distribution (or they are called
 *jointly* Gaussian random variables) if for all choices of real
numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, the 
random variable $a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\cdots+a_nX_n$ is a Gaussian random
variable.

As the OP has noted, this implies that the *marginal* distributions of
the $X_i$ are Gaussian. Note that also that when each $a_i$ is $0$,
the sum is also $0$ and we are accepting this constant as a
*degenerate* Gaussian random variable (cf. the extended discussion
in the comments following *[this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30160/6633)*).

Inserting the latter definition into the former, we get the description
of Gaussian random process used by the OP. Note that each random variable from a Gaussian random process is indeed a Gaussian random
variable. That is, the answer to the OP's question

> Are marginal distributions of the random variables comprising a jointly gaussian random vector always Gaussian?

is an unequivocal **Yes**.